# Can I buy Eurail pass offline? Are there any physical locations?

Tags: paris, eurail

My departure dates are closer and I couldn't order an Eurail Pass online. When I check to order it now it seems that they couldn't ship the pass to me before my departure. Even the premium shipping also couldn't make it. So I would like to know whether there are any physical locations in Paris where I can buy EuRail pass. Also would it be expensive than buying it from online?

Comment: Which pass do you want to buy? Can't you order it to your hotel/the place you stay at?

Comment: If I answered your question, please consider accepting the answer (Tick the check next to my answer), so people know it's answered.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Eurail web page](http://www.eurail.com/help/ordering-pass/can-i-buy-eurail-europe) you can only buy the following Eurail passes in Europe (and they are more expensive):

> - Eurail Global Pass
> - Eurail Select Pass (only the following combinations)
> - Eurail Croatia Pass
> - Eurail Greece Pass
> - Eurail Hungary Pass
> - Eurail Ireland Pass
> - Eurail Italy Pass
> - Eurail Norway Pass
> - Eurail Portugal Pass
> - Eurail Romania Pass

where the combinations the Eurail Select Pass is available in are:

> - Austria-Croatia-Slovenia
> - Austria-Hungary
> - Croatia-Slovenia-Hungary
> - Greece-Italy
> - Hungary-Romania

So if you want one which is not on this list, you'll be out of luck. However, if the pass you want is on the list, you can buy it at the  [Eurail aid offices](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/travel-resources/eurail-aid-offices) in Paris which are located at (you have to scroll down in the link) (highlighting is mine):

> **Gare de Lyon**
>
> Open:
>   Mon-Son: 6:00 am - 8:30 pm
>   Hall 3:
>   Mon-Fri: 5:45 am - 8:45 pm
>   Saturday: 6:00 am - 8:45 pm
>   Sun, bank holidays: 7:00 am - 8:00 pm
>
> **Gare Saint-Lazare**
>
> Open:
>   Mon-Thu and Sat: 6:15 am - 9:00 pm
>   Sun, bank holidays: 7:15 am - 9:00 pm

However, also Sta Travel is an [authorized sales agent](http://www.eurailgroup.org/Rail%20Passes/Where%20to%20buy%20Eurail%20Passes.aspx) of Eurail passes and they have an [office](http://www.statravel.fr/contactez-nous.htm) which is open Monday to Saturday at

> Adresse :
>   2 rue de Cicé 75006 Paris
>
> Métro :
>   Vavin (ligne 4) ou Notre-Dame des Champs (ligne 12)
>
> Horaires d'ouverture du lundi au samedi :
>   Matin : 10h00 - 12h30
>   Après-midi : 13:30 - 18:00

Note however, that you can also order Eurail passes to [european addresses](http://www.eurail.com/help/ordering-pass/can-i-buy-eurail-europe), so maybe you should contact your hotel or the place you stay at, and have the Eurail pass waiting for you when you get to Europe. I'm not sure whether the same restrictions apply as for buying it in person: I tried though to put a Eurail pass for France into my cart and select France as the shipping country and didn't have any problems (though obviously I didn't buy it so you might have problems later on during checkout).